# Error Importing Interface in Angular2

Tags: angular, interface

I am new to Angular2. I was trying to implement Interface and then importing it in another component but I keep on getting the following error:

**ERROR in /app/employee/employeeList.component.ts (5,10): Module '"/app/employee/employee"' has no exported member 'IEmployee'.**

I did find a couple of posts on StackOverflow and I did try the solutions provided but they didn't resolve my issue.

File1: employee.ts

```
export interface IEmployee {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  annualSalary: number;
}
```

File2: employeeList.component.ts

```
import { IEmployee } from './employee';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-employee',
  templateUrl: './employeeList.component.html',
})

export class EmployeeListComponent {
employees: IEmployee[];
selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton = 'All';

constructor() {
 this.employees = [
{ code: 'e1', name: 'Tom', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 5600 },
{ code: 'e2', name: 'Sam', gender: 'Male', annualSalary: 6600 },
];
}
```

Below is the structure of my files:

[image]

Comment: When exactly do you see this error? Are you using the angular cli, and ng serve? If so, you will have to stop and restart ng serve to get this to clear.

Comment: Have you tried closing everything (IDE, terminal, etc)? _Everything_, even file browser. Then pop it back open and try an `ng serve`. Your code is correct as far as importing the interface, so the only reason you're probably getting that error is because the file is in use somewhere else and you can't read the current version for some reason or another.

Comment: @R.Richards I am using Angular cli and ng serve. I see the error as soon as I save and my code compiles. I see that error in ng serve window. Can you tell me how to restart ng serve?

Comment: @Z.Bagley I have tried restarting IDE, terminal and even my browser but I still get the error.

Comment: @R.Richards Actually I figured out how to restart ng serve and then I had to restart the browser again and it worked!! Problem solved!!